# Error Ora-12545 on APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_request

Tags: oracle, web-services, oracle12c, acl

I have an error when i try to connect to a web service using apex , it always gives error *ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist* i cant even connect to google, when i check *dba_host_aces* i have the permission to resolve and connect. the problem is that i am not sure if i need to do something with the oracle server to allow the apex to run or open ports or something, i have been using this guide [oracle-base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_web_service-consuming-soap-and-rest-web-services) to make the function that calls the webservice

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: changed the p_url and p_action with or without http, www, granted and revoked ace priviledges, changed ports of aces and added an ace to call google.cl

Comment: Can you resolve+connect to these URLs outside of Oracle DB on your server? e.g. `telnet google.com 80` or `wget google.com` This will test whether it's a network issue or not.